# Sampling and Reconstructing Signals In Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, sample

I have this continuous signal :

```
x(t) = cos(100*pi*t)+cos(200*pi*t)+sin(500*pi*t)
```

I must apply the standard reconstruction of the sampling theorem with `f=500HZ`

Then I have to repeat it, with `f1>f`

Any help guys? I'm confused with signals and matlab!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sampling at `f=500Hz` means taking samples every `T = 1/f = 1/500 = 2ms`.

I don't know the units of your `t` vector and the length is also not specified.

Let's assume the length is 1 second and the units are in `us`.

You can create a sampling vector `tsample` every `2ms` (which corresponds to f=500Hz) and then get the value of your signal at this points.

```
freq = 500;
period = 1/freq * 1000000;       % to convert to us
tsample = 0:period:1000000;     % samples from 0 to 1 second every 2000us
sampled_signal = x(tsample);
```

PD: Probably this is a school exercise where you have to see what happens if you don't satisfy the Nyquist criteria. So try different sampling frequencies and see what happens if you don't sample fast enough.

Comment: x(t) , t ε [-10,10] and Δt=0,001

Comment: The code I posted will sample your signal at the frequency that you specify. Just adapt the units and duration to your needs